# Importing my .js file into mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

here's the problem, I have a small jquery function in my login.cshtml at the end of the code, like this and It works, but I want to do it in a seperate file and don't know how to format my new .js file and how to imported back into my view?

```
   @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
```

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".form-control:first").focus();
    });
</script>

}
```

So I tried and created separeted js file in my Scripts folder, in my BundleConfig.cs file added

```
**bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/login").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/app/account/login.js"));**
```

And in my login.js file:

```
$(function () {
    $(".form-control:first").focus();
});
```

But it doesn't work, why? I'm not sure how to call it or am I missing something?

Comment: You can import your js file just like jQuery js file. Place this `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/app/account/login.js">` after `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by BundleConfig.cs?

Comment: Have you using `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/login")` after `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`? What error you've found on browser dev tools console? Since that custom script uses jQuery, the order of load should be jQuery first, followed by your own script.

Comment: this helped, thx